# Pass a simple ViewModel from a View to a Controller via hidden field

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass a simple object containing only one field (a DateTime) from my view back to my controller.

I have a ViewModel that looks like this:

```
public class TheViewModel
{
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
}
```

I have a controller post method that looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> StartNew(TheViewModel viewModel)
{
    ....
}
```

In my view, my model is set to TheViewModel, and I am trying to simply send the same value for the StartTime field of the ViewModel back to the Controller:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.StartTime, new { id = "StartTimeField" })
    <input type="submit" value="Start" />
}
```

However, the value of the StartTime field is always the default date time. I have verified that this is not the value for the time sent to the view (by looking at the page source)

What am I mnissing?

Comment: You need to show us the GET method (best guess is that you have a parameter in your model for `StartTime` (or `TheViewModel`) an its value has been added to `ModelState` - and you can check this by adding `ModelState.clear()` before your `return View(...);`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a new object inside the HtmlFor?  Why not just `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.StartTime)` ?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer